# Send a email with content my domain to inbox Gmail

Tags: email, gmail, spam

When i send a email with content my domain, it putting in spam gmail. my domain is [`neginph.com`](http://www.neginph.com) and ip it is `50.115.44.157`.
How cand put this email (content my domain) in inbox gmail. what do i do?

Answer (score 0):

I your e-mail is being put in SPAM, you won't be able to do anything. The mailbox server controls the SPAM with its own algorithm.

Try to add your email@domain to trusted senders list and write e-mails with less content.

Read more about best pratices to prevent SPAM: http://msg.wikidoc.info/index.php/Spam_best_practices